# Run React + Redux and AngularJS in single webapp - Migrating page by page

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, migration

We have an Angular 1.3 based webapp and would like to migrate it to React + Redux. What would be the best course of action, where we can have the Homepage as React, and the remaining as Angular, and slowly move one page at a time to React.

My major doubts are with respect to routes. Which framework should handle the routes?

Are there any other things that I should be worried about?

Answer (score 0):

Alas, maybe my question was too open ended or was not worthy of an interest from any.

1. Was forced to use a reverse proxy setup with express (served on
   localhost://3000) with cors being enabled.
2. Few routes (/, /page1) redirecting to a http-server serving the React app on port 3001.
3. And the remaining routes (/cart, /somethingElse) redirecting to a http-server serving the Angular app on port 3002.

This was just a dev setup.

In prod setup, the pages are being served by Akamai and hence was beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I've written an article describing how we went about this in BigPanda - https://medium.com/bigpanda-engineering/gradually-migrating-from-angularjs-to-react-redux-a4a16585d3ff.

The gist is keeping the app wrapper in AngularJS, gradually replacing AngularJS components with React ones, and then at some point in the future when all components are converted, removing the surrounding AngularJS code and replacing it with React as well.